# How to send single email notification after uploading multiple image via Laravel & DropZone?

Tags: php, laravel, email, dropzone.js

I'm creating an Image Editing order system, where a user can upload multiple images by DropZone & Laravel. I want to implement after successful image upload image information save to database & send User an email notification. Then redirect to another page with session message. My code sends more than 1 email every time when saving data to the database. But I need to send an email when all image data successfully saved to the database. Here my code:

```
$order = Order::find($request->input('order_id'));
         $order->images()->create([
          'order_id' => $request->input('order_id'),
          'file_name' => $filename,
          'file_size' => $file->getClientSize(),
          'file_path' => $path . '/' . $filename,
          ]);

    // When all file details saved to database send Single Notification mail
  $data = array(
        'fullname' => $order->user->fullname,
        'email' => $order->user->email,
        'order_number' => $order->order_number
    );
    Mail::send('emails.order-submit', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('test@gmail.com');
        $message->to($data['email']);
        $message->subject('Order Submit');
    });
```

Here is my Full Controller Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Model\Order;
use Session;
use Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Images1Controller extends Controller
{

        public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

     public function doImageUpload(Request $request) {
          //get the file from the post request
          $file = $request->file('file');

          //set the  file name
          $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
          //move the file to correct location
          $order_number = $request->input('oid');
          $username = Auth::user()->username;
          $path = 'orders/'. $username .'/' . $order_number;
          if(!file_exists($path)){
              mkdir($path, 0777, true);
          }

          $file->move($path, $filename);

          //save the multiple/single file details to database
          $order = Order::find($request->input('order_id'));
            $order->images()->create([
              'order_id' => $request->input('order_id'),
              'file_name' => $filename,
              'file_size' => $file->getClientSize(),
              'file_mime' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
              'file_path' => $path . '/' . $filename,
              ]);

             Session::put('success','Your order has been submitted successfully.');
             $data = array(
            'fullname' => $order->user->fullname,
            'email' => $order->user->email,
            'order_number' => $order->order_number
        );
        Mail::send('emails.order-submit', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->from('test@gmail.com');
            $message->to($data['email']);
            $message->subject('Order Submit');
        });



    }
}
```

DropZone Configuration Code:

```
Dropzone.options.uploadImages = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFilesize: 2048,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',

    init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-images")
        addImages = this; // closure

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();         
      addImages.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
    });
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
      // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
    });

    this.on("success", function() {
         if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8000/user/orders/manage/';
      }
    });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is DropZone send single request instead of multiple request if

`uploadMultiple: true,` on DropZone Configuration. Now need update controller code as :

```
 foreach($file as $key => $value) {
        //save the multiple/single file details to database  
        $order->images()->create([
          'order_id' => $request->input('order_id'),
          'file_name' => $file[$key]->getClientOriginalName(),
          'file_size' => $file[$key]->getClientSize(),
          'file_mime' => $file[$key]->getClientMimeType(),
          'file_path' => $path,
          ]);
        //Move Files to destination path
        $file[$key]-> move($path, $file[$key]->getClientOriginalName());
      }
```

Here is updated Full Upload Method:

```
public function doImageUpload(Request $request) {
      //get the file from the post request
      $file = $request->file('file');
      //move the file to correct location
      $order = Order::find($request->input('order_id'));
      $order_number = $order->order_number;

      $now = Carbon\Carbon::now();
      $year = date('Y', strtotime($now));
      $month = date('M', strtotime($now));
      $datetime = date('Ymd', strtotime($now));

      $username = Auth::user()->username;
      // public/orders/year/month/date/username/order-number
      $path = 'orders/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/' . $datetime .'/' . $username . '/'  . $order_number;


      foreach($file as $key => $value) {
        //save the multiple/single file details to database  
        $order->images()->create([
          'order_id' => $request->input('order_id'),
          'file_name' => $file[$key]->getClientOriginalName(),
          'file_size' => $file[$key]->getClientSize(),
          'file_mime' => $file[$key]->getClientMimeType(),
          'file_path' => $path,
          ]);
        //Move Files to destination path
        $file[$key]-> move($path, $file[$key]->getClientOriginalName());
      }
      // Send Email Notification to User & Admin
    $time = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    Mail::to($order->user)->later($time,new PlaceOrder($order));
    Mail::to('test@gmail.com')->later($time,new NewOrder($order));
    Session::put('success','Your Order Submitted Success.');
    return $order; 
}
```

Here is updated Full DropZone Configuration:

```
   Dropzone.options.uploadImages = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFilesize: 2048,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',

    init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-images")
        addImages = this; // closure

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();         
      addImages.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
    });
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
      // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
    });

    this.on("success", function() {
         if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8000/user/orders/manage/';
      }
    });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$order = Order::find($request->input('order_id'));

foreach( $request-order_id as $key=>$val){
  $order->images()->create([
      'order_id' => $request->input('order_id'),
      'file_name' => $filename,
      'file_size' => $file->getClientSize(),
      'file_mime' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
      'file_path' => $path . '/' . $filename,
      ]);
}

// When all file details saved to database send Single Notification mail
$data = array(
    'fullname' => $order->user->fullname,
    'email' => $order->user->email,
    'order_number' => $order->order_number
);

Mail::send('emails.order-submit', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
    $message->from('test@gmail.com');
    $message->to($data['email']);
    $message->subject('Order Submit');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

FORM input should be like this

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple />
```

And code for the doImageUpload method is

```
if ($request->hasFile('images')) {

    $files = $request->file('images');

    foreach($files as $file) {
        //set the  file name
      $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      //move the file to correct location
      $order_number = $request->input('oid');
      $username = Auth::user()->username;
      $path = 'orders/'. $username .'/' . $order_number;
      if(!file_exists($path)){
          mkdir($path, 0777, true);
      }

      $file->move($path, $filename);

      //save the multiple/single file details to database
      $order = Order::find($request->input('order_id'));
      $order->images()->create([
          'order_id' => $request->input('order_id'),
          'file_name' => $filename,
          'file_size' => $file->getClientSize(),
          'file_mime' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
          'file_path' => $path . '/' . $filename,
       ]);
     }

    Session::put('success','Your order has been submitted successfully.');
    $data = array(
        'fullname' => $order->user->fullname,
        'email' => $order->user->email,
        'order_number' => $order->order_number
    );

    Mail::send('emails.order-submit', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('test@gmail.com');
        $message->to($data['email']);
        $message->subject('Order Submit');
    });
}
```